# How to optimize execution time for update statement?

Tags: oracle, sql-update, oracle19c

I'm trying to update a table which contains 137459 records. My query is running with Cost: 4, but it doesn't execute.

My executing query is following:

```
UPDATE TF_IMPORT_BILL_ISSUE N
   SET N.OPERATION_ID =
          (SELECT TRANSACTION_ID
             FROM (  SELECT /*+ INDEX(BT TF_IMP_BILL_TXN_BILLID) */
                           MAX (BT.TRANSACTION_ID) TRANSACTION_ID, BI.BILL_ID
                       FROM TF_IMP_BILL_TRANSACTIONS BT,
                            TF_IMPORT_BILL_ISSUE BI,
                            CONV_BRANCH_INFO BRANCH
                      WHERE     BRANCH.IS_FOR_MIGRATION = 1
                            AND BI.OPERATION_ID IS NULL
                            AND BRANCH.BRANCH_ID = BI.OWNER_BRANCH_ID
                            AND BT.BILL_ID = BI.BILL_ID
                   GROUP BY BI.BILL_ID) v
            WHERE v.bill_id = n.bill_id)
 WHERE N.BILL_ID IN (SELECT bill_id
                       FROM (  SELECT /*+ INDEX(BI) */
                                     MAX (BT.TRANSACTION_ID) TRANSACTION_ID,
                                      BI.BILL_ID
                                 FROM TF_IMP_BILL_TRANSACTIONS BT,
                                      TF_IMPORT_BILL_ISSUE BI,
                                      CONV_BRANCH_INFO BRANCH
                                WHERE     BRANCH.IS_FOR_MIGRATION = 1
                                      AND BI.OPERATION_ID IS NULL
                                      AND BRANCH.BRANCH_ID = BI.OWNER_BRANCH_ID
                                      AND BT.BILL_ID = BI.BILL_ID
                             GROUP BY BI.BILL_ID) V);
```

Also execution plan is given below:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                  | Name                      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT                           |                           |     1 |    52 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UPDATE                                    | TF_IMPORT_BILL_ISSUE      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                             |                           |     1 |    52 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                            |                           |     1 |    52 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     VIEW                                   | VW_NSO_1                  |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      SORT GROUP BY                         |                           |     1 |    58 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS SEMI                    |                           |     1 |    58 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS                        |                           |     1 |    52 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |         INDEX FULL SCAN                    | TF_IMP_BILL_TXN_BILLID    |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TF_IMPORT_BILL_ISSUE      |     1 |    39 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |          INDEX FULL SCAN                   | TF_IMPORT_BILL_ISSUE_ONBR |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | CONV_BRANCH_INFO          |     2 |    12 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | CBI_BR_ID                 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                      | SYS_C0016767              |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID             | TF_IMPORT_BILL_ISSUE      |     1 |    39 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |   VIEW                                     |                           |     1 |    26 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |    SORT GROUP BY                           |                           |     1 |    71 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |     NESTED LOOPS                           |                           |     1 |    71 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |      NESTED LOOPS                          |                           |     1 |    45 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | TF_IMPORT_BILL_ISSUE      |     1 |    39 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 20 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                   | SYS_C0016767              |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 21 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED  | CONV_BRANCH_INFO          |     1 |     6 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | CBI_BR_ID                 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  23 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED   | TF_IMP_BILL_TRANSACTIONS  |     1 |    26 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 24 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                     | TF_IMP_BILL_TXN_BILLID    |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   9 - filter("BI"."OPERATION_ID" IS NULL AND "BT"."BILL_ID"="BI"."BILL_ID")
  11 - filter("BRANCH"."IS_FOR_MIGRATION"=1)
  12 - access("BRANCH"."BRANCH_ID"="BI"."OWNER_BRANCH_ID")
  13 - access("N"."BILL_ID"="BILL_ID")
  19 - filter("BI"."OPERATION_ID" IS NULL)
  20 - access("BI"."BILL_ID"=:B1)
  21 - filter("BRANCH"."IS_FOR_MIGRATION"=1)
  22 - access("BRANCH"."BRANCH_ID"="BI"."OWNER_BRANCH_ID")
  24 - access("BT"."BILL_ID"=:B1)
```

Please help me how can I optimize this query to execute.

**Note:** Query's reference table records are TF_IMPORT_BILL_ISSUE (137,459), TF_IMP_BILL_TRANSACTIONS (239,712) and CONV_BRANCH_INFO (2).

Comment: `explain` is sometimes not optimal and show estimates, while the actual execution deals with actual values. You need to retrieve **actual** execution plan: use `dbms_xplan.display_cursor` or `dbms_sql_monitor.report_sql_monitor` with `format => 'ALL ALLSTATS LAST'` and `/*+gather_plan_statistics*/` hint to see if these estimates are correct (rowcount 1 seems to be a missing stats). If `A-Rows` are different from `E-Rows` then it would be better to collect stats on all the involved tables with `cascade=>true` and retry

Comment: Do you have any `BEFORE UPDATE` or `AFTER UPDATE` triggers on the `TF_IMPORT_BILL_ISSUE` table? Triggers can negatively affect performance if they're doing a lot of work, but that work won't be reflected in the optimizer cost estimates.

Comment: @astentx FORMAT is not a parameter to REPORT_SQL_MONITOR. Also, the gather_plan_statistics hint is also not needed for a SQL Monitor report. I would recommend simply passing in the SQL_ID and a TYPE=>'ACTIVE'

Comment: @BobC Yes, format was about `dbms_xplan` to include actual values (which are present in SQL monitor by default). `dbms_sql_monitor` is way more useful to troubleshoot performance issues, but it requires additional Diagnostic pack licence, while xplan is available in XE and is enough as a starting point.

Comment: @Mat you get stats of my query from following google sheet link.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FSHl6Z4wGIZq3DKIeKfAORX_3gKZg0FvlGAOu4WfbjQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: @BobC there has no trigger on `TF_IMPORT_BILL_ISSUE `.

Answer (score 0):

How about `merge`?

```
MERGE INTO tf_import_bill_issue n
     USING (  SELECT bi.bill_id,
                     MAX (bt.transaction_id) transaction_id
                FROM tf_imp_bill_transactions bt
                     JOIN tf_import_bill_issue bi ON bt.bill_id = bi.bill_id
                     JOIN conv_branch_info branch ON branch.branch_id = bi.owner_branch_id
               WHERE     branch.is_for_migration = 1
                     AND bi.operation_id IS NULL
            GROUP BY bi.bill_id) x
        ON (x.bill_id = n.bill_id)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET n.operation_id = x.transaction_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO TF_IMPORT_BILL_ISSUE N
USING (
  SELECT /*+ INDEX(BT TF_IMP_BILL_TXN_BILLID) */
         MAX (BT.TRANSACTION_ID) TRANSACTION_ID,
         BI.BILL_ID
  FROM   TF_IMP_BILL_TRANSACTIONS BT
         INNER JOIN TF_IMPORT_BILL_ISSUE BI
         ON (BT.BILL_ID = BI.BILL_ID)
         INNER JOIN CONV_BRANCH_INFO BRANCH
         ON (BRANCH.BRANCH_ID = BI.OWNER_BRANCH_ID)
  WHERE  BRANCH.IS_FOR_MIGRATION = 1
  AND    BI.OPERATION_ID IS NULL
  GROUP BY BI.BILL_ID
) v
ON v.bill_id = n.bill_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET N.OPERATION_ID = v.TRANSACTION_ID;
```